# Indenting SQL in another major mode in Emacs

Tags: sql, emacs, elisp, indentation

Oftentimes I'm writing some script to do some stuff, often involving SQL, in a different major mode.  Maybe it looks like this:

```
sql = """
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row_awesomeness > 1000
"""
```

I'd like to be able to indent the SQL propertly, so it looks something like:

```
sql = """
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE row_awesomeness > 1000
"""
```

I'm not picky about the SQL indentation algorithm used, but I can't get anything to work at all.  I'm not a huge fan of [`sql-indent.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/sql-indent.el), but I can't even get that to work using it in a new buffer (the function `sql-indent-buffer` doesn't change anything from my first description, and I definitely want the `SELECT`, `FROM` and `WHERE` clauses to be on separate lines which I think is pretty standard).

Ideally, I would highlight the region that contains the SQL and do something like <kbd>M-x</kbd> `sql-indent-region` <kbd>RET</kbd> - no need for something that indents upon a newline.

Comment: You should checkout mumamo which enables multiple-major modes. As I don't use I can't give you more guidance

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it (*lightly* tested, using the indenting function you mentioned -- I don't work with SQL but you should be able to plug in any function in its place as long as it operates on the whole buffer):

```
(defun my-sql-indent-region (beg end)
  "Indent the SQL statement in the region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      ;; http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/sql-indent.el
      (sql-indent-buffer))))
```

If I mark the following sql query (from "SELECT" through "f2.PLAYERID"), embedded in an elisp
string, and do <kbd>M-x</kbd> `my-sql-indent-region` <kbd>RET</kbd>:

```
(defvar my-sql-query "
SELECT p1.PLAYERID, 
f1.PLAYERNAME, 
  p2.PLAYERID, 
f2.PLAYERNAME 
FROM PLAYER f1, 
                   PLAYER f2, 
    PLAYS p1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN PLAYS p2 
        ON p1.PLAYERID < p2.PLAYERID 
    AND p1.TEAMID = p2.TEAMID 
GROUP BY p1.PLAYERID, 
    f1.PLAYERID, 
   p2.PLAYERID, 
    f2.PLAYERID 
HAVING Count(p1.PLAYERID) = Count(*) 
  AND Count(p2.PLAYERID) = Count(*) 
    AND p1.PLAYERID = f1.PLAYERID 
AND p2.PLAYERID = f2.PLAYERID;
")
```

I end up with:

```
(defvar my-sql-query "
SELECT p1.PLAYERID, 
    f1.PLAYERNAME, 
    p2.PLAYERID, 
    f2.PLAYERNAME 
FROM PLAYER f1, 
    PLAYER f2, 
    PLAYS p1 
    FULL OUTER JOIN PLAYS p2 
    ON p1.PLAYERID < p2.PLAYERID 
    AND p1.TEAMID = p2.TEAMID 
GROUP BY p1.PLAYERID, 
    f1.PLAYERID, 
    p2.PLAYERID, 
    f2.PLAYERID 
HAVING Count(p1.PLAYERID) = Count(*) 
    AND Count(p2.PLAYERID) = Count(*) 
    AND p1.PLAYERID = f1.PLAYERID 
    AND p2.PLAYERID = f2.PLAYERID;
")
```

Answer (score 0):

I use polymode.

```
(defun python/init-polymode ()
  (use-package polymode
    :ensure t
    :mode ("\.py$" . poly-python-sql-mode)
    :config
    (setq polymode-prefix-key (kbd "C-c n"))
    (define-hostmode poly-python-hostmode :mode 'python-mode)
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'poly-python-sql-mode)
    (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'define-python-keybindings))

  (define-innermode poly-sql-expr-python-innermode
    :mode 'sql-mode
    :head-matcher (rx "r" (= 3 (char "\"'")) (* (any space)))
    :tail-matcher (rx (= 3 (char "\"'")))
    :head-mode 'host
    :tail-mode 'host
    )
```

I then defined a couple of functions that can be applied to the current chunk.

```
(defun python-indent-sql-chunk ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((chunk (pm-chunk-range))
         (beg (car chunk))
         (end (cdr chunk)))
    (sqlformat-region beg end)
    (indent-region-line-by-line beg end)
    (delete-trailing-whitespace beg end)
    (sqlup-capitalize-keywords-in-region beg end)))
```

In order to make this happen every time I press enter:

```
defun sql-format-chunk ()
  (interactive)
  (newline-and-indent)
  (python-indent-sql-chunk)

(define-key sql-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'sql-format-chunk)
```